# Le corbeau et le renard : même « maître », même sens etc. ?

Tags: sens, expressions, usage, littérature, zoologie

Dans une fable bien connue, dont on a déjà justement dit qu'elle était l'une  de cinq fables marquant « l'imaginaire collectif français » et faisant « partie du fonds culturel commun, en dehors de toute "spécialisation" savante »<sup>1, 2</sup>, l'auteur présente ainsi ses protagonistes :

> **Maître** Corbeau, sur un arbre perché,
>  Tenait en son bec un
>   fromage.
>  **Maître** Renard, par l’odeur alléché,
>  Lui tint à peu
>   près ce langage :
>  [...]
>
> [ [*Le corbeau et le renard*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Corbeau_et_le_Renard) ([I, 2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livre_I_des_Fables_de_La_Fontaine)) de [Jean de La
>   Fontaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_de_La_Fontaine), 1668, je souligne ]

---

On nous dit que le mot *maître* a une *spécialisation professionnelle*, laquelle le rend apte à l'emploi comme « titre à l'adresse de certains métiers ». De là procède l'emploi en *appellatif* devant un prénom d'une personne de la classe moyenne (*maître Pierre*). On nous dit qu'on conserve les traces de ce dernier emploi dans... « les appellations plaisantes données au animaux de La Fontaine » (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sup. A. Rey, ed. *Le Robert*, 2011, à l'entrée *maître*, dont on vient de paraphraser certains des éléments).

Le *TLFi* présente dans sa section sur l'emploi de [*maître*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ma%C3%AEtre) comme appellatif (III.), on trouve deux types d'emploi qu'on note comme *vieux ou régional*, dont celui avec le prénom (B.) pour s'adresser aux agriculteurs propriétaires. Puis on dispose de trois emplois par allusion à la littérature (D.) : le *maître [aliboron](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aliboron)* (le sot, popularisé par La Fontaine même dans [I, 13](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Voleurs_et_l%27%C3%82ne)), *Maître Jacques* (la référence à [*L'Avare*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Avare) (première 1668) de Molière, le cocher qui est cuisinier, qu'au lexique on définit comme un [*factotum*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/factotum), le *subalterne*, presque le *serviteur*), et enfin un emploi par imitation de La Fontaine (« Sitôt pétris, sitôt soufflés, Maître Serpent les a sifflés, Les beaux enfants que vous créâtes! », Valéry, *Charmes*). L'[entrée](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ma%C3%AEtre/48734) au Larousse est aussi intéressante. Généralement l'[origine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/ma%C3%AEtre/1) de l'emploi en appellatif tout court remonte à Chrétien de Troyes (ds. [*Chevalier au lion*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Yvain_ou_le_Chevalier_au_Lion), v. 1170 : « Ne vous vaut,
Que vous n'en istrés or, biau mestre. [...] »).

---

- Considérant les versions d'[Ésope](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Fables_d%E2%80%99%C3%89sope/Le_Corbeau_et_le_Renard) et de [Phèdre](http://agoraclass.fltr.ucl.ac.be/concordances/Phedre_fablesI/lecture/3.htm), pense-t-on qu'il s'agisse dans la fable de La Fontaine
  du même sens de *maître* qui est employé autant pour le corbeau que pour le renard ; quels sont ce ou ces sens le cas échéant ; s'il n'y a qu'un sens/emploi quel mot pourrait aujourd'hui en tenir lieu dans la fable ?
- La référence qui alimente Molière et La Fontaine est-elle celle du *maître aliboron* ou l'idée de *spécialisation* ; la connotation principale aujourd'hui de *maître + prénom/nom d'animal* est-elle toujours celle de l'aliboron, ou bien celle du *subalterne* (Molière), ou est-ce uniquement « plaisant » vu l'importance qu'a la fable de La Fontaine ; cet emploi ne survit-il que par référence à la littérature ?
- Brièvement, qu'est-ce qu'un emploi *appellatif* : s'agit-il d'un substantif ou ce maître a-t-il la fonction d'un
  [adjectif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ma%C3%AEtre/1) devant le nom de ces animaux ; le cas échéant le sens est-il différent ?
- Brièvement, le *maître Pierre* de la classe moyenne dont parle le DHLF est-il l'*agriculteur propriétaire* dont parle le TLFi ; le *maître Jacques*
  dont parle Molière ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Michel P. Schmitt, *La place et l'image de La Fontaine dans l'enseignement durant la décennie*, dans *Le Fablier*, 1991, dont on présente un bref extrait sur ce [site](http://www.la-fontaine-ch-thierry.net/corbrena.htm).</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Au Québec, j'ai dû apprendre cette fable par cœur à la petite école, mais je préfère [*La cigale et la fourmi*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Cigale_et_la_Fourmi_(La_Fontaine)) (I, 1).</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Je pense que les deux emplois ici ont le même sens, sans nuance suivant qu'il s'agit du corbeau ou du renard. Cette appellation a aussi un aspect *agrandissant* (qui peut être ironique suivant le contexte): il ne s'agit pas de n'importe quel corbeau ou renard, mais d'un corbeau et d'un renard qui représentent parfaitement leur espèce respective, dans toutes ses spécificités: l'exemple même du corbeau et du renard, le corbeau et le renard *par excellence*, ce qui va faciliter la portée générale de la morale de la fable. Ni Ésope, ni Phèdre ne semblent avoir recours à une telle appellation. Je pense que le terme *monsieur* pourrait remplacer *maître*, si on voulait vraiment remplacer *maître*. Mais *maître* s'utilise encore de nos jours dans certains cas, par exemple pour s'addresser à un avocat ou un notaire.
- *Maître + prénom/nom d'animal* n'est pas courant. Je ne pense pas qu'il n'y ait jamais eu un sous-entendu de sottise ou de stupidité dans la fable de La Fontaine, ni de subalterne.
- Une appellation serait plutôt un *titre*, cf. exemple de l'avocat et du notaire ci-dessus.
- Le *maître Pierre* de la classe moyenne n'est ni un agriculteur propriétaire, car son métier n'est pas forcément l'agriculture, et il n'est pas riche comme un propriétaire, ni *maître Jacques*, car je soupçonne Molière d'ironie, qui n'est pas forcément présente dans *maître Pierre*.

Comment: Merci ! La représentation parfaite/ _l'exemple même_ / _le corbeau et le renard par excellence_, très bon. Diriez-vous que c'est une spécialisation ou bien une généralisation ; ce serait la spécialisation d'un type dans le règne animal pourrait-on dire ? Brièvement, ces _maîtres Jacques/Pierre_ sont-ils usuels pour vous ou ces références sont-elles de notoriété chez qqn. qui a le BAC ?

Comment: Je pensais plutôt que c'était une généralisation, que les deux animaux en question devenaient des _représentants_, _prototypes_ ou _archétypes_ de leur espèce. Je me suis demandé s'il y avait de l'ironie, mais je ne pense pas: La Fontaine pourrait être ironique à l'encontre du corbeau, qui est vaniteux, mais pas à l'encontre du renard, qui est plus fin, et il utilise le même _maître_ pour les deux, donc sans doute aucune ironie ici. De nos jours, je pense que même les bacheliers n'auraient aucune référence pour comprendre _maîtres Jacques/Pierre_, qui ne sont pas du tout usuels.

Comment: _Ici s'intégrerait trop facilement une critique de notre enseignement_ ;-)

Comment: Mais peut-être aussi _spécialisation_, dans le sens que l'on isole une qualité de l'homme, par exemple la _vanité_ dans le cas du corbeau, qui devient alors l'archétype de l'homme vaniteux.